# How to pass multiple var to sharepoint new item url?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have 3 webparts on a list display.aspx (the last two are connection webparts to the first which is parent for both ), I used the following script to finds the “Add New Item” link on the Child list and hijacks the element’s href attribute to call the "NewItem2" following this method

```
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26 
var issueID = getParameterByName("ID");

var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");

$(anchorElement).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time/NewForm.aspx?IssueID="  + issueID + "');");
```

When I try to pass two different ids,it override the first issueID and pass issueID2 for both url and redirect to Time2 NewForm.aspx when +new item is clicked.

What I am looking is when +new item clique for the different webparts the url redirect to their respective. For the first +new item redirect NewItem.aspx of the list one (Time) and For the second +new item redirect NewItem.aspx of the list two (Time2)

```
var issueID = getParameterByName("ID");

var issueID2 = getParameterByName("ID"); 

var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");

$(anchorElement).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time/NewForm.aspx?IssueID="  + issueID + "');");

$(anchorElement).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time2/NewForm.aspx?IssueID2="  + issueID2 + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
var issueID = getParameterByName("ID");
var issueID2 = getParameterByName("ID"); 
var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");
$(anchorElement).eq(0).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time/NewForm.aspx?IssueID="  + issueID + "');");
$(anchorElement).eq(1).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time2/NewForm.aspx?IssueID2="  + issueID2 + "');");
```

Comment: How can I pass additional attributes( column name = col3 (dropdown) to the bottom url once I grab the ID from the query string so that the child can access it on newform.aspx?  
            
$(anchorElement).eq(0).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://<URL TO SITE>/Lists/Time/NewForm.aspx?IssueID="  + issueID + "');");

Comment: If my reply solve your issue, you can mark the reply as answer, if you have new question, you can create a new thread, it would make others easier to focus on one question in one single thread and it will benefit other community members who stuck with the same question.